# Getting data from a Bidirectional One to Many Relationship in Hibernate/Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

As following the instructions or tutorials posted online on how to create a bidirectional One To Many relationships in Hibernate, I was able to create two entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "user_name",nullable = false)
private String userName;

@Column(name="password",nullable = false)
private String password;

@OneToMany (mappedBy = "user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<BlogPost> blogPostSet;

//getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "blog_post")
public class BlogPost {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String title;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String content;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name ="user_id")
private User user;

//getters and setters
}
```

I was able to insert data on these two entities, but the problem occurs when I try to fetch data a recursion happens and results to a stackoverflow error, please see the attached screenshot. What would be the proper way to fetch data on this hibernate relationship?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mapping seems to be fine, probably you have overridden toString() method in both of the entities printing each others relationship references like

```
class Employee{
public String toString(){
    return "blogPostSet "+blogPostSet;
}
class BlogPost{
public String toString(){
    return "employee "+employee;
}
```

Hence calling each others toString() to cause a stackoverflow error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `toString()` method, of both classes so that it doesn't get recursive. By changing that you can yourself print the things you want so that it doesn't go into recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Since the both entity has id as the field name,you have to specify @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id") and it will resolve the issue.